# html_notebook ignores global chunk options

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

**Is there a way to use [global chunk options](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/) in [`html_notebook`s](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/r_notebooks.html)?**

This html_document only shows the title (as desired in this MWE):

````
---
title: "Test"
output: 
 html_document
---

```{r setup, echo=FALSE}     
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE, results='hide', fig.keep='none')

```

```{r}        
1+1
plot(1:5, 1:5)
```
````

However, the very same document as an `html_notebook` shows all code chunks and output (the global chunk options are ignored):

````
---
title: "Test"
output: 
 html_notebook
---

```{r setup, echo=FALSE}     
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE, results='hide', fig.keep='none')

```

```{r}        
1+1
plot(1:5, 1:5)
```
````

I do not think this is intended, as I can supply the chunk options to the chunk directly and get the desired result (only the title):

````
---
title: "Test"
output: 
 html_notebook
---

```{r setup, echo=FALSE}     
library(knitr)

```

```{r echo=FALSE, results='hide',  fig.keep='none'}        
1+1
plot(1:5, 1:5)
```
````

Comment: Looks like a bug in the html_notebook renderer. I added an issue: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1077