# knitr opts_knit$set(root.dir = "../") ignored when chunk_output_type: console

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

My actual working directory of a .Rmd file is `"C:/Users/Camilo Erasso/Documents"`. I want to change it using `knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir ="D:/CAMILO")` in the setup chunk.

This works fine whit the default YAML option: `editor_options: chunk_output_type: inline`. But when I change this option to `editor_options: 
chunk_output_type: console` the new working directory is ignored or not changed.

I'm not used to work whit inline result (I prefer the console), for that reason I use this option. The same option can be changed in `RStudio>Tools>Global Options...>R Markdown>Show output inline for all R Markdown documents (uncheck)` or in the `.Rmd setting buttom (next to Knit buttom)> Chunk Output in Console`

Toy example:

````
---
title: "Example root.dir change"
author: "Camilo Erasso"
date: "2 de abril de 2019"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
getwd() #[1] "C:/Users/Camilo Erasso/Documents"
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir ="D:/CAMILO")
```

```{r}
getwd() #[1] "D:/CAMILO"
```
````

But when using the console output option:

````
---
title: "Example root.dir change"
author: "Camilo Erasso"
date: "2 de abril de 2019"
output: html_document
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
getwd() #[1] "C:/Users/Camilo Erasso/Documents"
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir ="D:/CAMILO")
```

```{r}
getwd() #[1] "C:/Users/Camilo Erasso/Documents" or NOT CHANGED
```
````

This problem is slightly different from this: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1575

And related whit this: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1077
and this [html_notebook ignores global chunk options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41911487/html-notebook-ignores-global-chunk-options).

Is this and RStudio issue? Thanks for your help!!!